# Magento 2 API Reference

Tags: magento2, api, magento-community, magento-2.1, documentation

I cannot find an (official or not) API reference for Magento 2.

/!\ I'm not looking for the reference of the REST API (http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html) or SOAP API, but I'm looking for the internal API reference /!\

I can't believe there is no one :)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now there's **no official code reference documentation** if that's what you're asking.

Comment: And do you know a good, online, searchable and unofficial one ? or maybe that the best option is to generate all the phpdoc myself ?

Comment: @GaelCOAT I'm not aware of any unofficial website yet. I guess you'll have to go the php doc generation route

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the one within your magento 2 enviroment http://yourmagento2website.com/rest/default/schema

Comment: This is the REST API reference, I was looking for docs concerning internal Magento Classes usage.